# Error code 1066 sqlstate 42000 not unique table alias

Tags: mysql

I am getting this error call not unique table alias, Im not able to figure out the issue. I have a common date table connecting all. Also teacher table connecting two tables - Leave and Attendance. Please help

```
    SELECT
    trns_teacherattendance.Attendance_Status,
    trns_teacherattendance.Attendance_Month,
    trns_teacherattendance.AcademicYear_Id,
    trns_teacherattendance.School_Id,
    trns_teacherattendance.Bio_Code,
    trns_teacherattendance.IsActive,
    mst_holiday_teacher.Holiday_Name,
    dates.dates,
    leave_new_view_teacher.Leave_Status,
    mst_teacher.Teacher_Name,
    leave_new_view_teacher.LeaveDate
FROM
    trns_teacherattendancemapping
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    trns_teacherattendance
ON
    (
        trns_teacherattendancemapping.Bio_Code =
        trns_teacherattendance.Bio_Code)
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    dates
ON
    (
        trns_teacherattendance.Attendance_Date = dates.dates)
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    mst_teacher
ON
    (
        trns_teacherattendancemapping.Teacher_Id =
        mst_teacher.Teacher_Id)
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    leave_new_view_teacher
ON
    (
        mst_teacher.Teacher_Id = leave_new_view_teacher.TID)
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    leave_new_view_teacher
ON
    (
        dates.dates = leave_new_view_teacher.LeaveDate)
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    mst_holiday_teacher
ON
    (
        dates.dates = mst_holiday_teacher.Holiday_Date) ;
```

Comment: can you show the exact error? Also the school3600database is an optional part of the syntax and really distracts from the readability.

Comment: `on (  ... )` doesn't need `(` or `)` either

Comment: I have removed the optional part. This is the exact error msg "Error code 1066 sqlstate 42000 not unique table alias" . I have been working on this for 5 days and not getting the idea behind the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are joining twice to a table `leave_new_view_teacher` but you aren't giving it different aliases. Database can't know from which query/table you would like to reference your columns. Each join could pull different data/rows.

Assign aliases to these tables as a minimum requirement in this part:

```
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    leave_new_view_teacher AS lnvt1 -- here
ON
    mst_teacher.Teacher_Id = leave_new_view_teacher.TID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    leave_new_view_teacher AS lnvt2 -- and here
ON
    dates.dates = leave_new_view_teacher.LeaveDate
```

You will also need to properly classify columns in `SELECT` part:

```
SELECT
  ...
  lnvt1.Leave_Status, -- you're probably getting this from first join
  mst_teacher.Teacher_Name,
  lnvt2.LeaveDate -- this probably comes from second join
```

You also don't need the parentheses for each `ON` clause, so I've removed them.

Comment: Date and teacher id is linked to the same leave_status, if it is separated then the results will not match.

Comment: Please adjust to your solution, I can't possibly know what you have on your mind while writing this question. You're just probably picking the values in SELECT statement from one table then (an alias here).

Comment: Thats true Kamil, Your solution help me and i had a work around. But i wanted to understand, if teacherid is common for both tables and for the same two tables even date is common, y does it throw the error in the join? Because date column comes from the master date table. Also teacher id is required for linking. Any Insights?

Comment: @Santu it's good that you want to understand it. The reason for different naming is because as I've mentioned, even though you are joining twice to the same table, the columns that you join on can produce different results (rows), and this is why they are different and database can't know what you mean exactly if you don't write it down. Does that make sense?